In a JSON schema, can the editing of a specific property's value be restricted based on user permissions?
I have created a graph schema in JSON and need to restrict the editing of the values in specific properties to a specific user-group. For example, if the property is a Boolean type and it has been turned on, only members of that specific user-group should be allowed to change the Boolean, while all other users have read-only access to that property; or if a specific value has been entered in a string property (e.g. "Blue"), then similarly editing of that property is limited to that group (and others can view its value) who are the only ones who can change its value to "Red".
From researching this so far, I cannot find any instructions for creating such a value-editing restriction by property in the schema code. This leads me to conclude that this is not possible in a JSON graph schema - I would welcome responses and guidance either way on this, including on any other way this could be tried / achieved beyond such a property-based approach.

This is not something related to the JSON Schema specification. These are application layer requirements.  The schema is only to validate the data model, not the behavior of the interactions.
